# How to access Safari 7.0.6 with Sierra 10.12.1 OS

Tags: safari, macos, recovery

2013 MacBook Pro logic board died. Removed HD and connected to Desk Mac, can access everything but Safari, want to get bookmarks, says "7.0.6 not supported". Can anyone suggest procedure?

Comment: John, please post your 'edit' as a comment in IconDaemon's answer - it wouldn't fit here otherwise I would save you the trouble of re-typing it.

Answer (score 1):

In Safari 10, bookmarks are stored in ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist. I'm assuming they were stored the same way in v.7

You can open the file as text in BBEdit or TextWrangler, or use some sort of XML editor and extract the bookmarks from there.

The file doesn't neatly list the bookmarks for easy viewing. The bookmarks are embedded in xml code and will need to be extracted. Fortunately, the bookmark URL is just a text string. Here's a sample of a single bookmark for **www.themachelpdesk.com**:

```
                    <dict>
                        <key>ReadingListNonSync</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>neverFetchMetadata</key>
                            <false/>
                        </dict>
                        <key>URIDictionary</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>title</key>
                            <string>MHD</string>
                        </dict>
                        <key>URLString</key>
                        <string>http://www.themachelpdesk.com/</string>
                        <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
                        <string>WebBookmarkTypeLeaf</string>
                        <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
                        <string>606385FA-CF10-11DA-B301-000D93547AFA</string>
                    </dict>
```